# TensorFlow Norm (LRN) doesn't support GPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am running following code on Google Cloud ML using BASIC GPU (Tesla K80)

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10

LRN is taking the most amount of time and its running on CPU. I am wondering if following stats quoted in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py were obtained by running on CPU because I don't see thats the case.

### System        | Step Time (sec/batch)  |     Accuracy

1 Tesla K20m  | 0.35-0.60              | ~86% at 60K steps  (5 hours)

If I force it to run it with GPU it throws following error:

Cannot assign a device to node 'norm1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available. [[Node: norm1 = LRNT=DT_HALF, alpha=0.00011111111, beta=0.75, bias=1, depth_radius=4, _device="/device:GPU:0"]

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow 1.0.1

Comment: Adding more information. Based on https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/runtime-version-list its Tensorflow 1.0.1

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure you installed the TensorFlow GPU version?

Comment: It is running on Google Cloud ML on BASIC_GPU tier and other operations are executing on GPU. So I would assume its TensorFlow GPU version.

Comment: "I don't see thats the case." Are you seeing different performance characteristics (> 5 hours for training to 86%)? Or are you just pointing out that tf.nn.lrn isn't supported on GPUs?

Comment: I see different performance characteristics (> 5 hours for training to 86%) and I feel its related to tf.nn.lrn running on GPU.